# Shipment view page 404 error

Tags: magento2, migration, 404-page, shipment

I have migrated data from magento 1.9 to magento 2.2.4, Now in admin when i view shipment under sales -> Shipments it gives me 404 error.
How am i suppose to debug?
I have checked the .phtml file from where the form is displayed on view but it is not reaching over there.
when is go to sales -> Order -> edit -> shipments in left panel it is working fine when i view shipment
Any help would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you flush cache, reindex and test again?

Comment: I tried still same..

Comment: @Arjun, can you paste your 404 error URL here ?

Comment: is this shipment id `107636` is visible in shipment grid ?

Comment: yes it is visible in grid. Even i am able to see the view in sales->order->shipment but not in sales->shipments

Comment: @Arjun, can you provide URL to check or any screenshot of error page ?

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat i have added screenshot

Comment: check in database table `sales_shipment` and `sales_shipment_grid` have data or not ? `sales_shipment_grid` table is rendered for grid and `sales_shipment` is used for shipment view page. might be during migration these tables have not been populated.

Comment: I checked in both tables data is available

Comment: ok, then can you check this file exist in your system `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Shipment/Index.php` and `vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Shipment/AbstractShipment/Index.php`

Comment: @ShashankKumrawat yes both are there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85023/discussion-between-shashank-kumrawat-and-arjun).

Comment: @Arjun,  any luck on it ?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a routing issue, forwarding action to the other controller doesn't work as expected.

Can you try changing the below file around line 49

Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Shipment\AbstractShipment\View.php

```
$resultForward->setController('order_shipment')
                ->setModule('adminhtml')    // Change admin to adminhtml
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known issue that is fixed and the fix will come with 2.3.*

See here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12206 for the full thread and possible patches.

Comment: I have checked the link you provided but my 404 page as i mentioned is when i try to view sales -> shipment -> view in admin + i have checked this on fresh magento 2.2.4 and it is working fine so i feel like it is related to data migration